# Set Boxes in a table

Tags: tables, boxes

I have a tabular and I want to group certain elements.
All in all it shall look like this (just with straight lines :D)
[image]

How can I achieve that?
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccccccccc}
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
    12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23\\
    24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 \\
    36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 \\
    48 & 49 & 50 & 51 & 52 & 53 & 54 & 55 & 56 & 57 & 58 & 59 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `nicematrix` package has some handy features to add boxes to tables

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you employ the `colortbl` package and its `\arrayrulecolor` macro, along with `\cline` directives before the first row and after the final row. Optionally, change the line widths by resetting `\arrayrulewidth`; the default width of `0.4pt` may be too thin for your taste.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % load 'colortbl' package automatically

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\arrayrulecolor{red}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.8pt} % default: 0.4pt
    \begin{tabular}{| cc | c | *{9}{c} | }
    \cline{1-2} \cline{4-12}
     0 &  1 &  2 &  3 &  4 &  5 &  6 &  7 &  8 &  9 & 10 & 11 \\
    12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 \\
    24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 \\
    36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 \\
    48 & 49 & 50 & 51 & 52 & 53 & 54 & 55 & 56 & 57 & 58 & 59 \\
    \cline{1-2} \cline{4-12}
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you're free to use LuaLaTeX, you could replace the hardcoded chunk

```
     0 &  1 &  2 &  3 &  4 &  5 &  6 &  7 &  8 &  9 & 10 & 11 \\
    12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 \\
    24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 \\
    36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 \\
    48 & 49 & 50 & 51 & 52 & 53 & 54 & 55 & 56 & 57 & 58 & 59 \\
```

programmatically with a couple of nested `for` loops and a couple of judiciously chosen `tex.sprint` instructions:

```
    \directlua{
```

```lua
    for j=0,4  do
      for i=0,10 do tex.sprint ( j*12+i .. "&" ) end
      tex.sprint ( j*12+11 .. "\\\\" )
    end
```

```tex
    }
```

Comment: +1. I just want to add that in case on boxes where you need incomplete vertical lines,  you can  use `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{...}` and `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{...}` (or `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{...}` to frame a single column, although the verbosity of this command could make more attractive the tikz alternative, or use some custom macros.

Comment: @Fran - If the frameboxes should cover only some rows, rather than all rows (as is the case in the OP's example), the code to generate the rectangular frames would definitely become a lot more complicated. Let's see if the OP weighs in with further information about their exact formatting needs.

Comment: @Mico Wow thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Can you maybe help with some fine tuning? I get the same output as you, but the left line and the bottom line seem so be thicker than the other two. Can I change that?

And can I set upper line a bit higher, so that there is more space between the line and the numbers?

Comment: @Lereu - To create a bit more space between the top edges of the rectangles and the first row of numbers (as well as between the other rows), I'd issue the instruction `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}` or something like it. About the left and bottom lines looking thicker than the other two lines: Do check if that's a pdf browser "thing". E.g., does the apparent difference in line widths persist if you increase the magnification?

Comment: @Lereu - One more thing -- be sure to run `\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}` *before* executing `\begin{tabular}{...}`

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{*{12}{>{\fpeval{\value{iRow}*12+\value{jCol}-13}}c}}
        &&&&&&&&&&& \\
        &&&&&&&&&&& \\
        &&&&&&&&&&& \\
        &&&&&&&&&&& \\
        &&&&&&&&&&& \\
        \CodeAfter
        \tikz\draw[red,thick] (1 -| 1) rectangle (last -| 3) (1 -| 4) rectangle (last -| last);
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]